# Is it legal to replace a list by an other one in an Hibernate JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assume a Hibernate 4.2 JPA 2.0 entity `class EntityA`, it contains a `@ManyToOne` field `List<EntityB> bs`. Up to now I strongly believed that I must not replace `bs` by an `new` List, instead I have to use the list methods `clear`, `add` and `remove`.

To day I wanted to show a college that it will cause problems when I replace the List with an new one, but nothing strange happed, it worked, the database and the entity was updated correctly. Now I am confused: **Is it with the hibernate 4.x JPA 2 allowed to replace a collection of an persisted entity?**

The two enities, with a OneToMany relation ship, maintained by the one-site.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
   @Id long id;
   @OneToMany public List<EntityB>bs;
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
   @Id long id;
   hashCode and equals based on id
}
```

The test, that did not find a problem

```
@Test
@Transactional
public testReplaceSet {
   //given: a persistent entity a that contains a persistent entity b1
   EntityA a = this.entityManager.persist(new EntityA());
   EntityB b1 = this.entityManager.persist(new EntityB());
   a.bs = new ArrayList();
   a.bs = b1;
   this.entityManager.flush();

   //when: assining a NEW List with an new persistent Entity b2
   EntityB b2 = this.entityManager.persist(new EntityB());
   a.bs = new ArrayList();
   a.bs = b2;

   long aId = a.id;

   this.entityManager.flush();
   this.entityManager.clear();

   //then: the collection is correct stored
   EntityA AReloaded = this.entityManager.find(EntityA.class, aId);

   //here I expected the failure, but there was no!
   assertEquals(b2, AReloaded.bs.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Try the modification starting EntityB b2 = this.entityManager.persist(new EntityB()); in a new txn.  I'm not sure hibernate is so strict as to use words like "allowed" or "legal" but I've certainly had exceptions with that pattern.

Comment: How are the entity ids being set? If they are the same assertEquals should return true.

Comment: @Thiago Gama: good idea, but they are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

Problems may happen when replacing contents of a list must trigger some operation in the DB.

For example, one known pitfall regarding this scenario is related to lists with `orphanRemoval = true`/`CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`. In this case orphan removal won't be triggered when you replace a list.

Perhaps you may face other kinds of similar problems in different situations as well.